# Zend Framework 2 - Wrap Annotation Forms nicely in HTML

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, zend-form, zend-framework2

Finally it seems I found a way to use some kind of `ModelForm` via `AnnotationForms`.

I build (for the regular `Zend\Form`) the following to wrap my form element into a `Twitter Bootstrap` container

```
foreach ($form as $element) : ?>
<?php echo $element->getLabel() ?>
<div class="control-group <?php if($this->formElementErrors($element)) echo "error" ?>">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $element->getLabel() ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->formElement($element);
        if($this->formElementErrors($element)) ?>
            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $this->formElementErrors($element) ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I realized that this doesn't work with AnnotationForms for some reason. It creates the input fields but nothing else... Any ideas why that is? And how I can fix it?

*BTW: I'd love to have a solution where I can do the wrapping within my entity/form-definition to avoid having the same for loop on every page!*

Comment: I can't help with your question, but I can address your second question. If you override the FormRow view helper with this specific markup, you can simply say `foreach($form as $element) { echo $this->formRow($element); }` where the form row helper creates the above markup. The default ones looks like this: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormRow.php#L70-L151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that there is no nice and built-in solution. What a pitty...

Nevertheless I just put my code in a partial, defined two variables and went with this solution.

Works pretty smooth until now...

```
echo $this->partial('partial/form-partial', array(
   'form' => $this->form,
   'url' =>  $this->url('my-route', array('action' => 'my-action')))); ?>
```